# reflect.DeepEqual map[string][]string Giving False When Should be True

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

I am testing a function that creates an anagram dictionary from a slice of words (strings). I am comparing map[string][]string. When I test the function, using reflect.DeepEqual() I get false, when under further inspection, I find the maps to be identical.

Code:

```
//Given a slice of words, returns an anagram Dict - A Map of alphabetic hashes, to words of that hash
func AnagramDictFromWordSlice(wordlist []string) map[string][]string {
    var ad = make(map[string][]string)
    for _, word := range wordlist {
        hash := HashWord(word)
        if val, ok := ad[hash]; ok {
            ad[hash] = append(val, word)
        } else {
            ad[hash] = []string{word}
        }
    }
    return ad
}

//Given a word, returns that alphabetic hash of that word. e.g. "word" -> "dorw"
func HashWord(input string) string {
    s := strings.Replace(input, "'", "", -1)
    s = strings.Replace(s, "-", "", -1)
    s = strings.ToLower(s)
    ss := strings.Split(s, "")
    sort.Strings(ss)
    return strings.Join(ss, "")
}

func TestAnagramDictFromWordSlice(t *testing.T) {
    words := []string{"abaci", "aback", "abacus", "abacuses", "abaft", "abalone", "fabat", "cusaba"}
    expected := make(map[string][]string)
    expected["aabci"] = []string{"abaci"}
    expected["aabck"] = []string{"aback"}
    expected["aabcsu"] = []string{"abacus", "cusaba"}
    expected["aabcessu"] = []string{"abacuses"}
    expected["aabft"] = []string{"abaft", "fabat"}
    expected["aabelno"] = []string{"abalone"}
    actual := AnagramDictFromWordSlice(words)
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(expected, actual) {
        t.Errorf("\nExpected %v, \ngot %v", expected, actual)
    }
}
```

Again, after running the test, I get a false for the deep equals, even though the two maps, once printed out are identical. Is there something I've missed?

***EDIT:

I've updated the failing test to spit out more info. Code here.

```
func TestAnagramDictFromWordSlice(t *testing.T) {
words := []string{"abaci", "aback", "abacus", "abacuses", "abaft", "abalone", "fabat", "cusaba"}
expected := make(map[string][]string)
expected["aabci"] = []string{"abaci"}
expected["aabck"] = []string{"aback"}
expected["aabcsu"] = []string{"abacus", "cusaba"}
expected["aabcessu"] = []string{"abacuses"}
expected["aabft"] = []string{"abaft", "fabat"}
expected["aabelno"] = []string{"abalone"}
actual := AnagramDictFromWordSlice(words))
if !reflect.DeepEqual(expected, actual) {
    t.Errorf("\nExpected %v, \ngot %v", expected, actual)
    t.Errorf("Expected: %v, Got: %v, %t", expected["aabci"], actual["aabci"], reflect.DeepEqual(expected["aabci"], actual["aabci"]))
    t.Errorf("Expected: %v, Got: %v, %t", expected["aabck"], actual["aabck"], reflect.DeepEqual(expected["aabck"], actual["aabck"]))
    t.Errorf("Expected: %v, Got: %v, %t", expected["aabcsu"], actual["aabcsu"], reflect.DeepEqual(expected["aabcsu"], actual["aabcsu"]))
    t.Errorf("Expected: %v, Got: %v, %t", expected["aabcessu"], actual["aabcessu"], reflect.DeepEqual(expected["aabcessu"], actual["aabcessu"]))
    t.Errorf("Expected: %v, Got: %v, %t", expected["aabft"], actual["aabft"], reflect.DeepEqual(expected["aabft"], actual["aabft"]))
    t.Errorf("Expected: %v, Got: %v, %t", expected["aabelno"], actual["aabelno"], reflect.DeepEqual(expected["aabelno"], actual["aabelno"]))
    t.Errorf("Length of expected: %v, length of actual: %v", len(expected), len(actual))
}
```

}

And here is the error message.

```
--- FAIL: TestAnagramDictFromWordSlice (0.00s)
main_test.go:26: 
    Expected map[aabci:[abaci] aabck:[aback] aabcsu:[abacus cusaba] aabcessu:[abacuses] aabft:[abaft fabat] aabelno:[abalone]], 
    got map[aabci:[abaci] aabck:[aback] aabcsu:[abacus cusaba] aabcessu:[abacuses] aabft:[abaft fabat] aabelno:[abalone]]
main_test.go:27: Expected: [abaci], Got: [abaci], true
main_test.go:28: Expected: [aback], Got: [aback], true
main_test.go:29: Expected: [abacus cusaba], Got: [abacus cusaba], true
main_test.go:30: Expected: [abacuses], Got: [abacuses], true
main_test.go:31: Expected: [abaft fabat], Got: [abaft fabat], true
main_test.go:32: Expected: [abalone], Got: [abalone], true
main_test.go:33: Length of expected: 6, length of actual: 6
```

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates the behavior. Runing your code as shown works: https://play.golang.org/p/bomHKW6p_z

Comment: can you run the test with the -v flag? I have tried running it as is together with the -v flag but everything is passing

Comment: What version of go?

Comment: Version 1.7.3 on mac.

Comment: this just works: https://play.golang.org/p/wvb8JK2RKO